# Java CMS GC - Initial mark

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am reading about CMS GC and need some clarification.
On [website](https://plumbr.io/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms-implementations#concurrent-mark-and-sweep) we can find:

> Phase 1: Initial Mark. This is one of the two stop-the-world events during CMS. The goal of this phase is to mark all the objects in the Old Generation that are either direct GC roots or are referenced from some live object in the Young Generation. The latter is important since the Old Generation is collected separately.

References from Young generation to Old must be found, but how at this point Young Generation is scanned? Is it full scan like in minor GC?

Comment: But does it make full scan of all young generation?

Comment: What alternative does it have? It needs to find any strong references to the old gen after all. It's a bit unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that there are no other options, but it wasn't said : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> References from Young generation to Old must be found, but how at this point Young Generation is scanned? Is it full scan like in minor GC?

**Yes.** Whole young space is scanned.

**No.** It is not like minor GC. Young (minor) GC does not scan whole young space. Young collection is traversing object graph visiting (and coping) only live objects.

As you may guess, from may description initial scan could potentially a big contributor to GC pause. CMS usually does initial mark "soon after" young GC completed in assumption that young space is small at that moment.

Same concern is valid for remark phase of CMS, whihc also involves young space full scan. You can find more details about CMS mechanics in [my article](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html).